# How to extract current user input given in an html and saving it in local storage form before submitting form in angular

Tags: angular, local-storage, angular-forms

What I am trying to say is that I want to get the IFSCCode for a bank as the user enters it in the text field even before submitting the form .

**Currently I am using an onkey event which is like this in my component.ts file**

```
bankvalue = '0';
  
  onKey(event: any) {
    this.bankvalue = event.target.value ;
    console.log(this.bankvalue)
    
  }
```

**And after this I am saving this IFSCcode in my local storage**

```
localStorage.setItem("bankIFSCvalue",this.bankvalue);
  console.log(localStorage.getItem("bankIFSCvalue"))
```

**This is how I am caling this onkey event in html template**

```
<div class="form-row">
                            <div class="name">IFSCCode</div>
                            <div class="value">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <input class="input--style-5" type="text" name="ifscCode" (keyup)="onKey($event)">
                                   
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

**But the main problem with this code is that when ever I try to get the latest value of IFSCcode from local storage it always gives me the previous one and then in the next one it give sme the current one . It always gives me one previously entered value**

***So how should I deal with this issue of giving the previously entered value and not the current one.***

Answer (score 0):

I would swap `(keyup)` for `(input)` for that it updates when anything changes. What is user holds key down for a long time? You would probably miss some data (if it is important to track data as user writes). For example, it could be important to verify data as user writes it, is it the correct length, correct format etc. If that is not important, then keep the `(keyup)` event. I don't know where is the part where you update the storage, but I added - so we update right after something changes.

hmtl

```
<input class="input--style-5" type="text" name="ifscCode (input)="onKey($event)">
```

ts

```js
bankvalue = '0';
  
onKey(event: any) {
  this.bankvalue = event.target.value;
  console.log(this.bankvalue);
  this.updateStorage();
} 

updateStorage() {
localStorage.setItem("bankIFSCvalue",this.bankvalue);
  console.log(localStorage.getItem("bankIFSCvalue"));
}
```